# Linux suitable filesystem with large metadata

Tags: linux, filesystems, metadata

I got know [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/20464) the following:

> Most unices do not have a concept of file creation time. You can't make ls print it because the information is not recorded. If you need creation time, use a version control system: define creation time as the check-in time.

There it is mentioned that ext4 stores some such metadata but there is no easy way to use it in the `ls` command.

So I want to know

Which filesystem on Linux stores or allows users to store the following meta-data:

```
file creation time
date accessed
date last modified
```

that can be accessed by standard shell tools?

It seems NTFS supports a very large amount of metadata.

Comment: I haven't researched this, but I've seen posts about it. AFAIK, it's not really an OS problem as much as it is a file system one. I think ext4 and maybe btrfs, do have a file creation time field, but most other file systems do not. Also, it's a tricky concept to use because if the file has been modified since it was created (which it would always have been unless it was created with something like touch), it's not entirely clear (at least to me) what this field would really be good for - maybe for forensics. No idea about the standard utilities reporting as I have only used ext[34].

Answer (score 1):

Most filesystems don't support creation time, but that doesn't matter since the Linux kernel doesn't (yet?) have a way to ask for it.  See this [lwn article](http://lwn.net/Articles/397442/) for the details.

Modification time is what you see by default when you run ls.  Using `ls --time=atime` will show the last access time instead.

But keep in mind that those aren't necessarily accurate.  It's as easy as `touch -d yesterday foo.txt` to spoof the timestamp.  Or the filesystem could be mounted with an option like `noatime` or `relatime` which would make the access time inaccurate.

Comment: So I guess Linux (Unix) sucks on this compared to Windows. :(